# Activating JButton when radio button is enabled?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jradiobutton

I want to set my `JButton` enabled only when I check one radiobutton in my radiobutton group. How can I do that?

Comment: Show us what code you have so far. Do you have a specific question about something that's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itemStateChanged` event to detect the radio button enabled & do your stuff,

```
@Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            yourButton.enabled=true;
        }
        else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            yourButton.enabled=false;
        }
    }
```